# Fade in/out with detach()

Tags: jquery

I've written a simply function to scroll through a list of words when the list is clicked. I'd like to try and make this fade in/out, but using the jQuery methods results in some off behaviour. The code without fadein/out is:

```
function wordSlide(){
    var mover;
    $('.wordslide').click(function(){
        mover = $('li',this).first().detach();
        mover.appendTo( '.wordslide',this );
    });
}
```

with some CSS:

```
.wordslide li {
  display: none;
}

.wordslide li:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

I've tried adding fadeOut to the following line:

```
mover = $('li',this).first().detach();
```

But this does not work as expected. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the complete event of fadeout:

```
.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

e.g.

```
$('li',this).first().fadeOut(400, function(){ $(this).detach(); });
```

Here is a fiddle with example https://jsfiddle.net/nup92o3m/3/:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
</div>
<div id="container" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
</div>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#myDiv').fadeOut(800, function()
{ 
    var myDiv = $(this).detach(); 
  myDiv.appendTo('#container').fadeIn(800);
});
```

Comment: Seems like a great solution, unfortunately I'm getting this.detach() is not a function.

Comment: See the updates with fiddle, this needs to be $(this) inside the complete.

Comment: Thanks - just noticed that a second after posting, the functionality isn't quite right though still using the current CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/arvv7ffg/

Comment: You didn't copy the code correctly, I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arvv7ffg/1/

Comment: After the first click, all list items are visible?

Comment: You can just use css transitions if you change the css: https://jsfiddle.net/arvv7ffg/3/